# Show Tooltip at specific control position via code

Tags: c#, winforms, location, tooltip

I have a textBox that should display a tooltip with a explanation when the user types something wrong.

But i'm not able to put the tooltip in the correct position.

My text Box is inside a groupBox and a TabControl. I tried this:

`Point locationOnForm = new Point(this.Left + tabCon.Left + gbDocs.Left + tbKey.Left, this.Top + tabCon.Top + gbDocs.Top + tbKey.Top);`

`tooltipError.Show("Test", this, locationOnForm , 3000);`

But the position is always nearby, never in the right spot.

Comment: Where do you want it?  At some part of the TextBox, such as the bottom-right corner?

Comment: After the bottom-left point. Or anywhere near that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will position your tool tip on the right of your text box

```
tooltipError.Show("TT Text", myGroupBox, textBox1.Left + textBox1.Width + 5, textBox1.Top, 3000);
```

Notice - you need to set your GroupBox as window - your tool tip must be displayed in the same coordinates as text box. Works well.

On this note, why not use `ErrorProvider`, which specifically designed for this?

Comment: Hmm, I'm gonna look at the `ErrorProvider`. Thanks for your help. My mistake was the `this` in the place of the groupBox. :)

Comment: No problem. Also, if sometimes you need really reach validator - you can write it yourself. Use label and timer, make a user control and you can draw all sorts of things on it and make it flicker and whatever. And it is relatively easy as well

Answer (score 2):

You can get absolute positioning quite easily.  This example puts the ToolTip at the bottom-right corner of the TextBox.

```
Point pt = new Point(0, 0);
pt.Offset(textBox1.Width - 1, textBox1.Height - 1);
toolTipError.Show("Test", textBox1, pt, 3000);
```

Remember that the `Point` you provide to tooltip is relative to the `Control` you provide, in this case `textBox1`.